# How to update a variable inside the while loop and see the results?

Tags: python

I want to use a for loop to define a range and I would like to use a while loop to check a condition for every value inside this for loop and give me the results for different values of c, but unfortunately, my algorithm doesn't work and I don't know what my mistake is.

```
j=0
jl=[]
c=np.linspace(0,20,num=20)
for a in range(0,len(c)):
    while j<5:
        j=c[a]+2
    jl.append(j)
```

The result I am looking for is it puts different values of c inside the while loop and calculate j and check if it is bigger than 5 or not. if yes, it appends it to jl. Totally, I want to define a range with for loop with index and also check each value of this range inside while loop and get the results for j.
so expected results are j with values smaller than 5 (c[a]+2<5) and store the values of j in jl

Comment: You start with `j=0` and your while condition is `j>5` so it never runs.

Comment: @wwii sorry i wrote down wrongly here, i corrected it

Comment: Your example has `jl.append(j)` *outside/after* the for loop - is that intended? - it will only run once after the for loop is done.

Comment: @wwii actually I am new in programming, especially python, that's why I am not aware of my mistakes, this task is very important for me because I am going to write a program in the university. Actually, I don't know where should i put this append right now. I didn't get any results.

Comment: Please include the expect result in your question.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) ... [Visualize your code](http://pythontutor.com/)

Comment: You don't actually need the range here, because you never try to *assign* to `c[a]` or  use `a` for anything other than indexing `c`. Just iterate over `c` directly: `for item in c: while j < 5: j=item + 2; ...`.

Comment: @wwii I mentioned the expected results

Comment: @chepner thanks for your response, but as I mentioned before, in the university I am going to write an algorithm with while loop for example I defined a variable before while loop and I calculated another variable during while loop; However this time I am going to give different values for the first variable before while loop and see what will be the results for the variable inside the while loop that's why I wrote down my code like this to get an answer and use it in my algorithm. the task is to define a range before while, and get the different results, do you know how can i do it?

Comment: At the *top* of the for loop, before the while statement, you probably need to reset `j` to zero.

Comment: No sure why you need the while loop. If you want to check value of j, use an if statement after defining j.

Answer (score 1):

There is one problem in your code:

```
j=0
```

"While loop" never runs because his condition is j>5. Correct that and tell us if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Please double check if the following suggested solution covers all of your requirements. In any case I think *List Comprehensions* (e.g.  [compare section 5.1.3.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)) can help you.

```
c=np.linspace(0,20,num=20)
ls = [x+2 for x in c if((x+2)<5)]
print(ls)
```

Will result in the following output:

```
[2.0, 3.052631578947368, 4.105263157894736]
```

If you want to do more complex data manipulation, you can also do this with the help of functions, e.g. like:

```
def someManipulation(x):
    return x+2

ls = [someManipulation(x) for x in c if(someManipulation(x)<5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm doesn't work because

```
while j<5:
    j=c[a]+2
```

is an infinite loop for j = 0, a = 0.

What you probably wanted to write was:

```
for x in c:
    j = x + 2
    if j < 5:
        jl.append(j)
```

Still, the list comprehension version in the other answer does exactly the same, but better.